# Unable to put fields in separate columns in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a tableau report where my Row a dimension of CallMonth (Jan, Feb..) and Aggregated Survey count, but when I put the fields in the data row section the CallMonth and Surveys are combined in one column. How do I split the two fields in two separate columns?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to change the `Table Layout`. See what happens if you drop any one feature (other than these two) from 'Row' section?

Look for `Analysis -> Table Layout -> Advanced` in your version of Tableau Desktop. There you need to increase "Maximum levels of row labels" and "Maximum levels of horizontal row labels" to 16 or so. Now first two columns won't get merged. Hope this helps!

*Don't forget to let us know if it answered your query :)*

Comment: It works like a charm! thanks for the insights .. this is my first time learning tableau on my own. :)

Comment: glad that it helped :)